# RadWindow icon not shown in taskbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523357/rad-window-icon-not-displayed-on-task-bar-c-sharp-wpf) is wrongly marked as duplicate.

The [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525839/361100) works, but it's not XAML-ish doing. My self-answer post below is recommended from Telerik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Telerik example](https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/blob/master/Window/RadWindowAsMainWindow/CS/MainWindow.xaml), there are three lines in `MainWindow` as below;

```
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.ShowInTaskbar="True"
navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.Icon="icon.ico"
```

Of course, you should prepare `icon.ico` file.

Full xaml code is attached as below.

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="RadWindowAsMainWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
        navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.ShowInTaskbar="True"
        navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.Icon="icon.ico"
        Header="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="The application is shown inside RadWindow." />
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```